# Rails app on AWS can't access the ElasticSearch service but Rails console can

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a Rails application running on AWS and decided to add Amazon ElasticSearch (AES) to the application. I was able to make it run correctly if I go to the console and create indexes and run a search. However, if I try to run from the application (by going to the browser and running the page on the browser) the same search that works on the console  fails and provides the following error on the logs:

```
Started GET "/customers/search" for 168.0.184.214 at 2018-07-24 18:31:04 -0400
Processing by CustomersController#search as HTML
^[[1m^[[36mUser Load (1.8ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2^[[0m  [["id", 30], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 12.2ms)

Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound ([404] <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.0</center>
</body>
</html>
):

app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:8:in `map'
app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:8:in `search'
```

The code that causes that error on the controller is this one:

```
 class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   def search
     @page = params[:page] || 1
     @per_page = params[:per_page] || 10
     s = Customer.custom_search({first_name:'Paul'}).results.map(&:first_name)

   end
 end
```

Now if I run that search from the console, everything works.

The app is behind a nginx+Puma server.

My config file config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb looks like this

```
 config = {
   host: "https://vpc-t2-es-i5qqpdv4k4pvq3smnj3nc46f74.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/",
   transport_options: {
     request: { timeout: 10000 }
   }
 }

 Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)
```

And the nginx config file is: https://jpst.it/1jZl4

Does anyone have any suggestion of what could be wrong?

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using the gems: elasticsearch-model and elasticsearch-rails

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Could it be that  `rails c` runs in development mode and `rails s` is running production?

Comment: @DennyMueller I tried that but it works fine with any of the environments on the console (rails c)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was even easier than what I thought.

The problem was that Nginx is working with Puma, and restarting Nginx doesn't restart Puma processes so any changes I was trying were not being applied on the running application. That's why it worked on the console and not on the actual applicaiton

Basically restarting Puma solved the issue. Yes, as stupid as it sounds :)